# Select today's date as default

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question which I'm not sure if possible or not but let's say I have a table with Employeeid, Date and AttendanceStatus i.e "Present"/"Absent".

I can get the status of all employees for all dates or for dates I specify in the query.
My question is that is it possible to get today's date by default so whenever I run the query it give me the data rows for today's instead of all the records from the database. I want to use default so that I don't have to change the date everyday.
Thanks in advance

Comment: yes. it is possible. use `getdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from TABLE_NAME where 
where cast([Date] as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Also, as already mentioned, you could create a view:

```
create view V_TABLE_NAME as
select * from TABLE_NAME where 
where cast([Date] as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: Casting the date field would reduce the query performace. It is redundant. Use the daterange instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply where clause for current day;

```
select * from table where 
Date > cast(getdate() as date) and 
Date < DATEADD(day,1,cast(getdate() as date))
```

Or you can create a view;

```
create view v_table 
as
select * from table where 
Date > cast(getdate() as date) and 
Date < dateadd(day,1,cast(getdate() as date))
```

Then query;

```
select * from v_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Logic

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE
SELECT
*
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateField = ISNULL(@MyDate,GETDATE())
```

Here, If You are not passing any values in the Parameter @MyDate, it will take Current Date as Default. The following can also be used

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE
    SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE 
DateField = CASE WHEN ISDATE(@MyDate) = 1 THEN @MyDate ELSE GETDATE() END
```